# Не получается сделать простой запрос на SQLServer 2012

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Здравствуйте.Нужно отправить xml для процедуры в SQLServer 2012.Делаю вот так :

```
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        String SQL = "declare @response varchar(8000);<xml><action>login</action><login>test</login><password>147852</password></xml>, @response output; select convert(text,@response)";
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
        /*while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(4) + " " + rs.getString(6));
        }*/
    }
```

И получаю вот это :

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "<".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:885)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:778)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:677)
    at pakkket.MainClassDbo.main(MainClassDbo.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Помогите.. что делаю не так? Это не может быть из-за версии `JDBC` ?

Comment: Ну так и сделайте в своей хранимой процедуре входной параметр и передайвайте туда ваш @xml

Comment: Не вижу у вас в коде SQL-запроса...

Comment: @Nick Proskuryakov там есть процедура которая обрабатывает этот xml

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov да.я должен передать просто строки в тегах.Точно в такой форме.

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007 прежде всего вы должны вызвать хранимку, чтобы иметь возможность что бы то ни было ей передавать...

Comment: @ЭмЭрИкс_007 там это где? Как SQL поймет что вам нужно передать вашу строку в качестве параметра хранимой процедуре "N"?

Comment: @Nick Proskuryakov исправил String sql; Так должно быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем виде все должно выглядеть примерно так:

Ваша процедура на MS SQL:

```
    create procedure MY_PROCEDURE(@xml varchar(max))
    begin
        --обработка получаемого XML
    end
```

Ваш код на java:

```
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);){
        String xml = "<xml><action>login</action><login>test</login><password>147852</password></xml>";

        try(CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call MY_PROCEDURE(?)}");){
            callableStatement.setString(1, xml);
            callableStatement.execute();
        }
    }
```

За синтаксис извиняюсь, писал в блокноте.

Comment: Спасибо...заработало.